# Method overloading vs factory

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Lets say we need some logic change in multiple methods of multiple classes on basis of a flag, while keeping backwards compatibility.

There are two ways..

1.overload every method in every class. then end up with an if-else ladder in caller code to call correct method.

2.Make a common interface and a Factory. Return objects of either on basis of flag passed to factory. Callers don't need any change. only a little change is needed while object creation. Is it logical to create factory for two types only ?

Based on your experience which will you choose ? How to decide between these two ways ? Any better approach you can suggest ?

Comment: I suggest that you code up a realistic example using both approaches and see for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Logic change* suggests behavior which suggests the Strategy Pattern.  This avoids a change to the existing method signature.

But you can still use a factory to centralize the creation of the concrete strategy object which handles the logic.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.calculateSomething(new Random().nextBoolean());
    }

    private void calculateSomething(boolean isUsingLegacyLogic) {
        CalculationStrategyFactory factory = new CalculationStrategyFactory();
        CalculationStrategy strategy = factory.getCalculationStrategy(isUsingLegacyLogic);
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator(strategy);
        calculator.calculate();
    }

    class Calculator {
        CalculationStrategy calculationStrategy;

        Calculator(CalculationStrategy calculationStrategy) {
            this.calculationStrategy = calculationStrategy;
        }

        // ...

        public double calculate() {
            // original code
            // ...
            // System.out.println("Calculation steps were done in sequential order.");
            // return 0;


            return calculationStrategy.calculate(this);
        }

    }

    private interface CalculationStrategy {
        double calculate(Calculator c);
    }

    private class SequentialCalculationHandler implements CalculationStrategy {
        public double calculate(Calculator c) {
            // ...
            System.out.println("Calculation steps were done in sequential order.");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private class ParallelCalculationHandler implements CalculationStrategy {
        public double calculate(Calculator c) {
            // ...
            System.out.println("Calculation steps were done in parralel.");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private class CalculationStrategyFactory {
        public CalculationStrategy getCalculationStrategy(boolean isUsingLegacyLogic) {
            if (isUsingLegacyLogic || Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() == 1) {
                return new SequentialCalculationHandler();
            }

            return new ParallelCalculationHandler();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Awwwww!  I couldn't type fast enough you beat me to it.  I love the Strategy Pattern.  Yes, this problem is not a creational one but a behavioral one so you would "inject" the new implementation.